# Another way to update listbox values in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, listbox

I have a `ListBox` within a `ListView` that is populated by a `SqlDataSource`. This `ListBox` is in the `InsertItemTemplate` of my `ListView`.
Is there a way to select a value in the `ListBox`, click the update button and bring up a `TextBox` with the selected value so that the user can change the information to save and update? I was thinking if there is a way to bring up a popup window or `TextBox` that shows the selected value so I can update it.

```
<asp:ListView ID="FormSectionListView" runat="server" InsertItemPosition="FirstItem">
    //omitted other templates because I am not using them.
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <div style="font-size: .8em; display: block">
                    <asp:FormView ID="FormSectionFormView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FormSectionID" DataSourceID="FormSectionDataSource" RowStyle-VerticalAlign="NotSet">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Insert" 
                                                OnClick="FormSectionButton_Click" 
                                                Font-Size="1.2em" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton"
                                                runat="server"
                                                Text="Update"
                                                Font-Size="1.2em"/>              
                                </td>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <div style: align="center">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1"
                                                   runat="server"
                                                   Font-Bold="true"
                                                   Text="Section Instruction"
                                                   Font-Size="1.2em">
                                        </asp:Label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="width:800px; height:auto; overflow:auto">
                                        <asp:ListBox ID="SectionInstructionListBox"
                                                     DataSourceID="SectionInstructionSource"
                                                     runat="server"
                                                     DataTextField="Instruction"
                                                     Visible="True" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div style="padding-top: 4em; width:800px">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label5"
                                                   runat="server"
                                                   Font-Bold="true"
                                                   Text="Insert New Instruction"
                                                   Font-Size="1.2em">
                                        </asp:Label>              
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="SectionInstructionTextBox"
                                                     runat="server"
                                                     Width="800px" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>       
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:FormView>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Why is there ASP.NET code, but the question tagged as `wpf`?

Comment: @Herdo Sorry that was a mistake